# TSLint: Shadowed name in map. Is this false positive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, tslint

I have the following TypeScript / Javascript codes for producing multiple line using jQuery.

```
let evenLine = false;
   const divs = clientsInfo.map((m) => {
      const div = $('<li/>', { class: 'hubClientInfo' + (evenLine ? ' even' : ' odd') });
      evenLine = !evenLine;

      div.append($('<span/>', { class: 'hc-userAgent' }).text(m.userAgent));
      div.append($('<span/>', { class: 'hc-ip' }).text(m.ipAddress));
      div.append($('<span/>', { class: 'time' }).text(m.connectedTimeUtc.toString()));

      div.append($('<span/>', { class: 'hc-user' }).text(m.username));
      div.append($('<span/>', { class: 'hc-id' }).text(m.id));

      return div;
});
```

TSLint reports Shadowed name regarding to "evenLine".

Is this a false alarm?
or is there a way to improve the codes to avoid such alarm?

Comment: On what line is the warning reported?

Comment: It complained about "evenLine"

Comment: Which of the three lines that mentions `evenLine`?  Is there another `evenLine` in scope?

Comment: @Matt McCutchen, I use only let and const and no var, and there's no another evenLine in scope except those in the OP.

Comment: However, after 2nd check through search, I did find there's evenLine near the bottom having global scope. Thanks for your inspiration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually I had found that down the bottom of the TS file there's a "evenLine" declared globally outside any class or module. So renaming those "evenLine" within a function scope had fixed the TSLint warning, while the program has been working properly.